# Add CSS for html selector based on React state?

Tags: css, reactjs

I'd like to set `overflow-y: hidden` **for the `html` selector (not an element)** based on whether a React class component state variable is true. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, that is possible. you can do something like  `className={this.state.hidden ? "class to show" : " " }`

Comment: You can create a style object and apply it the same way. `style={this.state.hidden ? {"overflowY": "hidden"} : {} }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean you want to apply the overflow-y to the actual HTML tag then putting this code in the render worked for me

```
...
render() {
  let html = document.querySelector('html');
  this.state.test === "test" ? html.style.overflowY = "hidden" : html.style.overflowY = "visible";
  return (
   ....
  )
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
function MyComponent() {
    // Set your state somehow
    const [something, setSomething] = useState(initialState)
    // Use it in your className`
    return <div className={!!something && 'class-name'} />
}
```

If you have multiple class names to work with, a popular package is (aptly named) [`classnames`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames). You might use it like so:

```
import cx from 'classnames'


function MyComponent() {
    const [something, setSomething] = useState(initialState)

    return <div className={cx({
        'some-class' : something // if this is truthy, 'some-class' gets applie
    })} />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It's possible. You can do this.

```
function App() {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const htmlSelector = document.querySelector("html");
    htmlSelector.style.overflowY = visible ? "unset" : "hidden";
  }, [visible]);

  return (
    <button onClick={() => setVisible(prevState => !prevState)}>
      Toggle overflow
    </button>
  );
}
```

[See the full example on CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/lively-thunder-0dp8x?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`style`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style) property to set inline CSS:

```
<div style={{ overflowY: hide ? 'hidden' : 'auto' }}>
```